# Find the character in line?

Tags: batch, batch-file, ms-dos

I am trying to find the some character in file using find or findstr, for example file contents like:

> "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**_test1"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**.test2"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**(abc)**test3"
>   "/test/abctest/abci.txt = c:\abctest\tst\work\workt.txt;**abc**_test4"

... so on...
I want to find in file last "abc" (bold part).
This file very large, So I don't want to use any "for" loop to find a character.
Could you please suggest me any solution?

Comment: I’m confused.  I read the question and said to myself, “OP wants the last ***occurrence*** of `abc` ***on each line***.”  But now somebody has given you a way of finding the last ***line*** that contains a match, and you seem to like it.

Comment: What do you want to happen when it's found?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to install a package of Unix tools, like Cygwin, you can use the tac command (opposite of "cat") - it will read/display the file backwards. Then you can pipe that into findstr (or grep) to get the last matching string from the file. Some version of tail support the -r switch, which also reverses the order of lines in the file.

If this is not clear, leave me a comment & I'll elaborate.

UPDATE: Unix tools are available to use under Windows, if you install one of these: [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). Follow those links to install one or another & then you'll have what you need. FYI, CygWin seems to be the most popular and is the one I use.

Comment: Thanks for reply!! I am using windows 2007. Can you please suggest me for windows os.

Comment: See UPDATE to answer for using this solution under Windows.